# Subfigure and subtable side-by-side?

Tags: subfloats

[image]

I have to do something like above.I saw similar questions, but I didn't find anything about what I need to do exactly.

Here an example of what i did (it doesn't work as i want):

```
\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{figure.png} 
  \caption{Caption 1}
  \label{fig:fig1}
  \end{subfigure}
    
  \begin{subtable}[t]{}
  \scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    1 & 2\\ \hline
    11 & 22\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{Caption 2}
  \label{table:table}
  \end{subtable}
\caption{Caption 3}
\label{fig:mainfigure}
\end{figure*}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % do not use demo option in actual document.
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{figure.png} 
  \caption{Caption 1}
  \label{fig:fig1}
  \end{subfigure}
%
  \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    1 & 2\\ \hline
    11 & 22\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption 2}
  \label{table:table}
  \end{subtable}
\caption{Caption 3}
\label{fig:mainfigure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works with my example but when i take it into my overleaf text, with the real figure and table, Figure (a)  stays on the table. Not side by side. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: What does "stay on the table" mean? Does the figure oerlap with the table or do you get a figure with a table below it instead of next to it?

Comment: Don't you have a blank line between the end of the subfigure and the beginning of the subtable environments?

Comment: i get a figure with a table below it instead of next to it

Comment: Make sure, there is no empty line between subfigure and subtable. If you want to keep the empty line in order ton increase readability of the code, comment out the empty line as I did in my answer.

Comment: Yes, i already commented out the empty line. I added \scriptsize to my table and now it works. Thank you.